# multiplicity between tables on edmx shema

Tags: c#, edmx

I'm trying to understand an .edmx shema and i don't know what exactly means the "->" on the table name and what kind of multiplicity is.
I haven't saw something like this before..can you help me?

.edmx photo:
http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/706/50490471.png/

Answer (score 1):

The `→` in a UML class diagram signifies inheritance.

In your diagram `Drivers` inherits from `People`.

Comment: But it is better to make the general entity property, abstract to true. but its your own design desission.